# How to I select a random empty cell from a range of cells, until all cells in range have been selected?

Tags: excel, vba

First time VBA coder here, so I'm not quite sure where to start.

I'm creating a "quiz" wherein a macro selects a random empty cell within a set range (C9:014). The user then types something into the cell and presses Enter. Then, the macro selects another empty cell within the set range (C9:O14). The user again types something into the selected cell and presses Enter. This process repeats until all 78 cells in the range have been filled by the user.

I suspect that some sort of Do Until loop is involved.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks so much guys.

Comment: Share a bit of your code, please

Answer (score 1):

Welcome on board!

Using this code:

1. The game starts once you activate the sheet.
2. The player can't change the selection made by the code.

First, add this code to worksheet's Module (in worksheet code pane (right-click on the tab and select "View code") put the following):

```
Private Used_Range As Range, Quiz_Range As Range, ThisCell As Range, PreventSelect As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    FreshStart
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim n As Long, nMax As Long
    OnError GoTo ex
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Quiz_Range Is Nothing Then FreshStart
    If Not Used_Range Is Nothing Then
        If Used_Range.Address = Quiz_Range.Address Then
            If MsgBox("Game Over!" & Chr(10) & "Do you want to start over?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                FreshStart
            Else
                GoTo ex
            End If
        End If
    End If
    nMax = Quiz_Range.Cells.Count
    n = RandBetween(1, nMax)
    If Used_Range Is Nothing Then
        Set ThisCell = Quiz_Range.Cells(n)
        Set Used_Range = ThisCell
    Else
        Do Until Intersect(Quiz_Range.Cells(n), Used_Range) Is Nothing
            n = n + 1
            If n > nMax Then n = 1
        Loop
        Set ThisCell = Quiz_Range.Cells(n)
        Set Used_Range = Union(Used_Range, ThisCell)
    End If
    Quiz_Range.Cells(n).Select
ex:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    PreventSelect = False
End Sub
Function RandBetween(MinInt As Long, MaxInt As Long) As Long
    RandBetween = Int((MaxInt - MinInt + 1) * Rnd + MinInt)
End Function
Sub FreshStart()
    Set Used_Range = Nothing
    Set Quiz_Range = Range("C9:O14")
    Quiz_Range.ClearContents
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If PreventSelect Then
        ThisCell.Select
        MsgBox "You can't select another cell!"
    End If
    PreventSelect = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note: This random selector selects the next unused cell if the output of the Rnd function refers to a used cell.

---

**Edit #1**

Using the randomizing collection method by @HTH, the code can be much better:

```
Private coll As Collection, Quiz_Range As Range, ThisCell As Range, PreventSelect As Boolean
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    FreshStart
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim n As Long, nMax As Long, m As Long
    OnError GoTo ex
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Quiz_Range Is Nothing Then FreshStart
    If coll.Count = 0 Then
        If MsgBox("Game Over!" & Chr(10) & "Do you want to start over?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            FreshStart
        Else
            GoTo ex
        End If
    End If
    n = Int(1 + Rnd * (coll.Count))
    Quiz_Range.Cells(coll(n)).Select
    coll.Remove n
ex:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    PreventSelect = False
End Sub
Sub FreshStart()
    Set Quiz_Range = Range("C9:F14")
    SetColl Quiz_Range
    Quiz_Range.ClearContents
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If PreventSelect Then
        ThisCell.Select
        MsgBox "You can't select another cell!"
    End If
    PreventSelect = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
Sub SetColl(rng As Range)
    Set coll = New Collection
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To rng.Count
         coll.Add i
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @HTH thank you for the advice. Feel free to downvote or discuss. Both make Stackoverflow better, I think. And that's what we all want. Yes, I am sure it works now, and the other solution where I used your idea of using a collection works well too. Thank you.

Comment: I like your "Activate sheet -> fresh start" logic [+1!]. I'd add a `On Error GoTo ex` statement just before `Application.EnableEvents = False` in `Worksheet_Change()` to be sure events are enabled back should something ever go wrong. As for including my solution logic in your code: well that could be sort of a "stealing", but your are quite young in SO and it's fine for me in that you made efforts in learning something new. So let me steal the Activate idea from you!

Comment: I'm trying to help, too. Don't you agree? And the youth of yours I was mentioning was with respect to your SO life.

Comment: Commenting about the code is most welcome. Commenting about me is not! What is "SO life" BTW?

Comment: SO="StackOverflow"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210984/discussion-between-abdallah-el-yaddak-and-hth).

Answer (score 1):

in worksheet code pane (right clik on the tab and select "View code") put the following

```
Option Explicit

Dim quizRng As Range
Dim coll As Collection
Dim i As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not quizRng Is Nothing Then If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(quizRng) > 0 Then SelectCell Else MsgBox "game over"        
End Sub

Sub Start()
    Set quizRng = Range("C9:O14")
    With quizRng
        SetColl .Cells
        .ClearContents
        i = 0
    End With
End Sub

Sub SelectCell()
    Dim n As Long        
    With quizRng
        If coll.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        i = i + 1
        n = Int(1 + Rnd * (coll.Count))
        .Cells(coll(n)).Select

        coll.Remove n
    End With        
End Sub

Sub SetColl(rng As Range)
    Set coll = New Collection
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To rng.Count
         coll.Add i
    Next
End Sub
```

Then [add a Button](http://www.homeandlearn.org/add_a_button_to_a_spreadsheet.html) to your sheet and assign it the `Start` macro

The user will have to click the button to start the game and then just write into cells that are progressiveley selected by the code until the "game over" message

Edit

alternatively to a button, as in @AbdallahEl-Yaddak answer, you could have it al started by the sheet activating just adding the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    MsgBox "Start of the game!"
    Start
End Sub
```

Edit 2

changed

```
.Cells(m \ .Columns.Count + IIf(m Mod .Columns.Count = 0, 0, 1), IIf(m Mod .Columns.Count = 0, .Columns.Count, m Mod .Columns.Count))
```

to

```
.Cells(coll(n)).Select
```

thanks to @AbdallahEl-Yaddak

Comment: Using the collection is great! [+1]. But why did you use the statement with `IIF`? Would you explain? (trying to learn something new)

Comment: I used [`IIF()`] function to avoid an `If - Then - Else` block, mostly for the sake of keeping code compact although it could work against its readability. Anyhow, the use of `IIF()` must always be kept under strict control since it doesn't short-circuit

Comment: Sorry, it seems that my question was not clear enough. I meant what difference does this statement has than referring to the cell by its number? I think it would be very helpful if you add comments to the code explaining that statement. Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by  _"referring to the cell by its number"_?

Comment: `quizRng.Cells(m)`

Comment: Yes! it surely can be done. And it 'd shorten and make it more readable, too. That was a "survivor" of a previous attempt where it wouldn't work due to the scenario. I'll edit the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that all the cells in the block are initially empty:

```
Sub JustaGame()
    Dim rng As Range, arr(1 To 78) As Variant
    Set rng = Range("C9:O14")

    i = 1
    For Each r In rng
        arr(i) = r.Address(0, 0)
        i = i + 1
    Next r

    Call Shuffle2(arr)
    For i = 1 To 78

        addy = arr(i)
        v = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter a value for cell " & addy, Type:=2)
        Range(addy) = v
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub Shuffle2(InOut() As Variant)
    Dim o As Object, oc As Long, i As Long, io
    Dim j As Long, k As Long

    Hi = UBound(InOut)
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    ReDim helper(Low To Hi) As Variant
    Randomize


    Set o = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For Each io In InOut
        o.Add io
    Next io

    j = Low
    oc = o.Count - 1
    For i = 1 To oc
        k = Int((o.Count - 1 - 0 + 1) * Rnd() + 0)
        helper(j) = o.Item(k)
        j = j + 1
        o.RemoveAt k
    Next i

    helper(j) = o.Item(0)

    For j = Low To Hi
        InOut(j) = helper(j)
    Next j

    Set o = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note:

1. `arr()` is a complete list of the addresses in the block
2. `Shuffle2()` creates a random permutation of that list
3. the code fills the cells in the random order specified above

**EDIT#1:**

This version of `Shuffle()` does not need *ArrayLists*:

```
Public Sub Shuffle(InOut() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim tempF As Double, Temp As Variant

    Hi = UBound(InOut)
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    ReDim helper(Low To Hi) As Double
    Randomize

    For i = Low To Hi
        helper(i) = Rnd
    Next i


    j = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While j > 0
        For i = Low To Hi - j
          If helper(i) > helper(i + j) Then
            tempF = helper(i)
            helper(i) = helper(i + j)
            helper(i + j) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + j)
            InOut(i + j) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        For i = Hi - j To Low Step -1
          If helper(i) > helper(i + j) Then
            tempF = helper(i)
            helper(i) = helper(i + j)
            helper(i + j) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + j)
            InOut(i + j) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        j = j \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

In the main program, change:

```
Call Shuffle2(arr)
```

to:

```
Call Shuffle(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm getting an "automation error" upon running this code -- am I doing something wrong? Looks like it's specifically for the "Set o = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")" line.

Comment: @downinmyplums  You may need to set a reference.........I will investigate........if your environment does not support `System.Collections`, I will give you a different shuffle.

Comment: @downinmyplums  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: You're right, my VBA may not recognize System.Collections.

Comment: @downinmyplums  I posted a replacement.

Comment: Awesome! It works! Quick question -- is there any way to write the code such that the user inputs the value into the cell itself and presses [Enter], instead of inputting the value into a message box?

Answer (score 0):

Give the name of the range (on which you will play the game) in cell A1.

```
Sub quiz()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, target As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set target = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1").Value)
    Total = target.Rows.Count * target.Columns.Count
    random = Rnd(Total)
    For Each cell In target
    If cell.Value = "" Then
    cell.Select
        If cell.Row * cell.Column = random Then
        Exit For
        End If
    End If
    Next cell
    End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, It is tested.

Comment: Well, I cannot get it to work for a "C9:O14" address value in A1. Can you?

Comment: Remove the double quotes - type it as: C9:O14 and ensure that sheet name in the code matches with the worksheet name.

Comment: I already used it without double quotes (I'm not a novice). Your code dosn't work: 1) there's a logic flaw in `If cell.Row * cell.Column = random` 2) it's not really "random" since it'd always follow the `For Each cell In target` cells selection sequence